# Animating a DropShadowEffect on a control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a very simple animation where I animate the DropShadowEffect on a control using C#. From my little understanding of WPF I believed it was done this way;

```
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = 10;
        da.To = 50;
        da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        progressBar1.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadiusProperty, da);
```

It's a bright colored glow on a black background so I'm sure the glow is there and not moving. I've tried applying it to different controls as well. Am I missing something obvious?
But the code does absolutely nothing. I get no error either. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `BeginAnimation` function on the effect and not on the control:

This is the XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Width="200" Height="30" Name="progressBar1">
    <ProgressBar.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" x:Name="effect" >

        </DropShadowEffect>
    </ProgressBar.Effect>
</ProgressBar>
```

And here is the Code:

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.From = 10;
da.To = 50;
da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
effect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadiusProperty, da);
```

Comment: Ah! I knew I missed something blatantly obvious, thank you for clarifying this for me. It works now.